# Pass Props to Outlet in React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't manage to pass props to my Outlet components in the new react-router v6. I tried the straightforward solution:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Outlet name="My name" />
  );
}
```

And that correctly renders the child component, however no props are passed to the child. None of the examples provided by the React team (or anyone else for that matter) display Outlets with props, so I'm worried it's not actually a thing. Is there another way I'm not finding or am I using Output components incorrectly?

Edit: Seems there's no straightforward way to pass props, see answer below.

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can do it with
[outlet context](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.4/hooks/use-outlet-context)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only seems to support functional components. Is there any equivalent for class components, which are used in the question?

Comment: @Jordan Outlet component has `context` prop. To get it back inside outlet, just use `useOutletContext` inside functional component, and after wrap with this component code inside you class component. Example on the screen https://take.ms/SdJzf .Code exmpl https://pastebin.com/ikCE3CsB

Comment: Provide full answer with example. Eventually, links to third-party websites die or become updated.

Answer (score 23):

When using functional component declare the name in the parent component like this.

```
function Parent() {
  const const name='Your name'
  return <Outlet context={[name]} />;
}
```

Then in the child component do this

```
//import this
import { useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

function Child() {


const [name] = useOutletContext();



return <p >{name}</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This is now possible (from version 6.1.0) with the context prop

```
<Outlet context={}/>
```

[github issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7495#issuecomment-991276681)

[react router outlet docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext)

Answer (score 10):

An alternative option here is to use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share props from your parent view to your child view.

```
const Context = React.createContext({})

function ParentView () {
  const outlet = useOutlet()
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ foo: 'bar' }}>
      <h1>Parent View</h1>
      {outlet}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

function ChildView () {
  const props = React.useContext(Context)
  return (
    <div>child view {props.foo}</div>
  )
}
```

Another option (untested) may be to use [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to clone outlet and add props to it.

Comment: This is the best way to do this so far with RR6, worth marking this as the right answer @SchoolJava101

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately after digging for a while it looks like there's no straightforward way to do this and no plans to change it (at least for now), based on this GitHub issue's response https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7495.

Answer (score 2):

one way i did it and it works well is to create a reach context, if you know how to use react context, this will be easy for you.

In a separate file create Context.js to  prevent require loop

```
const AdminStoreContext = React.createContext();
```

and then export it

```
export{AdminStoreContext}
```

then in another file create a consumer and provider of the context, and then   import the context you've creates

```
import { AdminStoreContext } from "../../contexts";

class AdminStoreContextProvider  extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ===vlaues you want to share }
}



render() {
    return (
        <AdminStoreContext.Provider
            value={{
                ...this.state,//===spread the  value you want to  share
            }}>
            {
                this.props.children
            }
        </AdminStoreContext.Provider>
    );
   }
   }
   const AdminStoreContextConsumer = AdminStoreContext.Consumer;
    export { AdminStoreContextConsumer, AdminStoreContextProvider }
```

you can wrap your app with the  context

```
<AdminStoreContextProvider>
    <app/>
<AdminStoreContextProvider />
```

you can use either the consumer or the  context to  get the values  for the  purpose of Outlet, we use  the context

once again import it

```
    import { AdminStoreContext } from "../../contexts";

 const route[{
path: 'consumer',
element: <MyMainComponent AdminStoreContext ={AdminStoreContext }  />,
children: [
  { path: 'account', element: <MySubComponent1  /> },
  { path: 'purchaseHistory', element: <MySubComponent2  /> }
]
```

},

then in your MySubComponent1 or MySubComponent2

get the value from the  props and use

```
    const { AdminStoreContext  } = props;
const context = React.useContext(AdminStoreContext )
```

and from the context you an get your values, hope this is helpfull

```
context.//get any value you put on the state
```